# How to use custom jackson de-/serializer in kie execution server?

Tags: jackson, drools, kie-server

I am using Kie Execution Server 6.5 (docker image). I deploy a kie container (kjar) which contains some rules and some custom java classes. Everything was working so far.

Now, I added some 3rd party classes to my java classes ([geojson-jackson](https://github.com/opendatalab-de/geojson-jackson)
), which use a custom jackson serializer and deserializer declared with `@JsonDeserialize(using = LngLatAltDeserializer.class)`, see [LngLatAlt](https://github.com/opendatalab-de/geojson-jackson/blob/master/src/main/java/org/geojson/LngLatAlt.java).

First I had class loading issues, apparently because of different jackson versions, which I solved by using geojson-jackson 1.3 and excluding the jackson dependency in my `pom.xml`.

The container is now started successfully, but objects cannot be deserialized, because the custom deserializer is not used. I get a `MarshallingException` caused by

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of 
 org.geojson.LngLatAlt out of START_ARRAY token
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@33714932; line: 1, column: 385] (through reference chain:
 org.drools.core.command.runtime.BatchExecutionCommandImpl["commands"]->
 org.drools.core.command.runtime.rule.InsertObjectCommand["object"]->
 MYPACKAGE.MYCLASS["polygon"]->org.geojson.Polygon["coordinates"])
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
```

This is exactly the part the custom deserializer should take care of.

**Update:** Karel Suta's answer helped me to investigate further.

The issue 5776 to the PR indicates that annotating a DTO should be possible to extend the JSON marshaller. The new `JSONMarshallerExtension` should only be needed if the object model is not to be annotated.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPM-5776

https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/pull/851

Enabling debug log level for `org.kie.server`, I got:

```
DEBUG [org.kie.server.services.drools.DroolsKieServerExtension] (default task-1) Adding org.geojson.Polygon type into extra jaxb classes set
DEBUG [org.kie.server.services.drools.DroolsKieServerExtension] (default task-1) Added org.geojson.Polygon type into extra jaxb classes set
DEBUG [org.kie.server.services.drools.DroolsKieServerExtension] (default task-1) Adding org.geojson.LngLatAlt type into extra jaxb classes set
DEBUG [org.kie.server.services.drools.DroolsKieServerExtension] (default task-1) Added org.geojson.LngLatAlt type into extra jaxb classes set
...
```

and

```
DEBUG [org.kie.server.api.marshalling.BaseMarshallerBuilder] (default task-2) About to build default instance of JSON marshaller with classes [
..., class org.geojson.Polygon, org.geojson.LngLatAlt, ...
```

Together with over hundred other classes (all dependencies it seems). So the classes are recognized and maybe supplying a `JSONMarshallerExtension` for them would work (I have not figured out, how to do that), but it should be possible with annotations as well.

Any other suggestions to get the annotations working?

Comment: Are you sure that these tags attract people who can help you? This doesn't look like a Drools problem to me - none of the classes in the error message is org.kie...

Comment: @laune Updated the error message to show that it is called from drools code and added additional log output where kie server picks up the classes.

Answer (score 1):

In latest snapshot it could be possible to define custom marshaller for classes using JSONMarshallerExtension, see [this PR](https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/pull/851).